# How to wrap ItemsPanel in LongListSelector?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone, wrappanel, longlistselector

I am using listbox and wrappanel for displaying data.

For example:

```
    <ListBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplateListBoxAnimation}">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <toolkit:WrapPanel ItemHeight="150" ItemWidth="150">
                </toolkit:WrapPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplateListBoxAnimation">
        <Grid Width="130" Height="130">
            <Image Source="{Binding Image}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

It's look like:

[image]

Now **I need to use LongListSelector** and grouping result:

```
    <toolkit:LongListSelector ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplateListBoxAnimation}">
        <toolkit:LongListSelector.GroupItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <toolkit:WrapPanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </toolkit:LongListSelector.GroupItemsPanel>
    </toolkit:LongListSelector>
```

**But it's look like:**

[image]

**I need to get:**

[image]

**Your assumptions?
Thank you**

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that the `GroupItemsPanel` property is not changing the `ItemsPanel` of the main list, but rather the `ItemsPanel` of the group headers, as can be seen here (image from http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part2-data-binding-scenarios):

[image: group headers wrapped]

Unfortunately the WP toolkit doesn't seem to expose the `ItemsPanel` that you want, so you'll have to modify the toolkit source to get the behavior that you want.

1. Get the source from here: https://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/80797
2. Unzip, open up the Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.WP7.sln solution in Visual Studio.
3. Under the Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.WP7 project, open Themes/Generic.xaml
4. Scroll down to the `Style` that applies to `LongListSelector` (TargetType="controls:LongListSelector")
5. Change the `TemplatedListBox.ItemsPanel` to a `WrapPanel`

   ```
                   <primitives:TemplatedListBox.ItemsPanel>
                       <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                           <controls:WrapPanel/>
                       </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                   </primitives:TemplatedListBox.ItemsPanel>
   ```
6. Rebuild and reference the new dll, your items should wrap appropriately!

Comment: Excellent answer! Although a bit to hacky for me, so I'll stick with ListBox for now.

Answer (score 3):

You can override it by using custom style

```
<toolkit:LongListSelector 
                        Background="{StaticResource FCBackground}"  
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding NowShowingEvents}"
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource EventsListMediumItemTemplate}"  
                        IsFlatList="True" 
                        Style="{StaticResource LongListSelectorStyleCustom}"
                                >

                    </toolkit:LongListSelector>


   <Style x:Key="LongListSelectorStyleCustom" TargetType="toolkit:LongListSelector">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:LongListSelector">
                    <toolkitPrimitives:TemplatedListBox x:Name="TemplatedListBox" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <toolkitPrimitives:TemplatedListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                            </Style>

                        </toolkitPrimitives:TemplatedListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <toolkitPrimitives:TemplatedListBox.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <toolkit:WrapPanel Margin="24,0,12,24"/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </toolkitPrimitives:TemplatedListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    </toolkitPrimitives:TemplatedListBox>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```