# ItemsPanel property in Longlistselector control Windows Phone 8 SDK

Tags: windows-phone-8, longlistselector, itemspanel

Does anybody know if the Longlistselector control from Windows Phone 8 SDK (not Windows Phone toolkit for WP 7.5) has the ItemsPanel property or an equivalent?

The ListBox control has such property, i use it for wrapping the items in a WrapPanel.

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <toolkit:WrapPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

There is an answer here: [How to wrap ItemsPanel in LongListSelector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12341381/how-to-wrap-itemspanel-in-longlistselector) but this refers to the Longlistselector found in the Toolkit NOT in the WP8 SDK (where i do not have access to source code to use the mentioned solution).

Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this with the `LayoutMode` property. Set the value to Grid

> Gets or sets a value that specifies if the
>   Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector is in a list mode or grid
>   mode from the Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelectorLayoutMode
>   enum.

```
<phone:LongListSelector ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" LayoutMode="Grid" >
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked! I also had to set GridCellSize property.

Comment: Don't forget that an exception will be thrown if you don't also add the GridCellSize property, eg: <phone:LongListSelector ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" LayoutMode="Grid" GridCellSize="180,240" >